# How to include Boost Library for VS 2008(command line)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, boost, cmake

I want to [co-brand](http://trac.qutecom.org/wiki/Cobranding) [Qutecom](http://trac.qutecom.org/) and and make a customised Windows installer for it.

My **PATH** variables are set using the command prompt using a .bat file on a Win 7 Ultimate x64  machine.

The contents of the .bat file:

```
@echo on
@SET QTDIR=C:\Qt\4.7.4
@SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\Include
@SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\Include\atl
@SET INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2007)\Include
@SET LIB=%LIB%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\Lib
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\Bin
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\4.7.4\bin;c:\Program Files\Mercurial
@SET BOOST_ROOT=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0
@SET BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0
@SET BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0
@SET BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib
@SET BOOSTLIBDIR=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib
@SET LIB=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib
@SET LIBPATH=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib
@SET BOOSTINCLUDEDIR=C:\boost\boost_1_47_0
@SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

I've tried the following commands:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "NMake Makefiles"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" && cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"
```

I'm getting the following error message from Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt.

```
-- found boost includes in C:/boost/boost_1_47_0
-- found boost libs in TMP-NOTFOUND
-- found boost includes in C:/boost/boost_1_47_0
-- found boost libs in TMP-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at owbuild/FindBoost.cmake:569 (message):
  Could not find Boost
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libs/3rdparty/boost/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**How can I include the boost libs using command prompt & cmake ?**

**Attachment:** [FindBoost.cmake](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1762611/FindBoost.zip)
[CMakeLists.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1762611/CMakeLists.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the environment variables. CMake will not set its variables from environment variables, unless you set up `CMakeLists.txt` to read env vars and set cmake vars from them. It's doable, but I don't see the point.

I think you want to set variables on the cmake command line with `-Dvariable=value`:

`cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR="C:\boost\boost_1_47_0" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib" -DBoost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS="1.47.0"`

If that does not work, examine your `CMakeLists.txt` - are those variables being set to something different, overriding your command line settings?

If all else fails, look through `FindBoost.cmake`. Especially look at the comments at the top of the file - they explain what the various variables do.

sources: [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=findboost.cmake), [mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044133.html), [ml reply](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044135.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried your commandline parameters, but in vain. I'm attaching CMakeLists.txt found on the Boost folder on the 1st post.

Comment: @MithunJohnJacob - Judging from the copyright lines in your `FindBoost.cmake` and mine (which is from CMake 2.8.5), your version diverged from the official CMake version some time between 2006 and 2009.  I'd try to use the version that came with CMake. It should reside somewhere within `Program Files/CMake`, probably in a folder called `Modules`.  **Edit:** Also, if you aren't using the latest version of CMake, I would upgrade. From the comments in my FindBoost.cmake, new versions of boost frequently break that file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me try the steps mentioned by you.